# Is it good practice to bind directly to service in AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

Is there anything wrong with binding directly to a service in Angularjs, like this ?

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl(myService) {
    $scope.myService = myService;
}
```

View:

```
<button ng-click="myService.doSomething()"></button>
```

Or is is better to declare the methods and variables used in the view directly in the controller ?

Controller:

```
function MyCtrl(myService) {
    $scope.doSomething = myService.doSomething;
}
```

View:

```
<button ng-click="doSomething()"></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not. Yes its good practice. The goal of Service is to avoid code duplicate. Its like Utils.

If our project contains multiple controllers we can easily register our Service to each controller and use all methods stored in Service.

By the way its good practice also to define Service in different file so you can migrate your Service to other projects.

Moreover you can group several Services in one service. here is example:

```
myModule.factory('ajax_post', ['$http',
        function(_http) {

    var path = 'src/php/data.ajax.php';

    return{
        init: function(jsonData){
            var _promise= _http.post(path, 
                jsonData
                ,{
                    headers: {
                        'SOAPActions': 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems'
                    }
                }
                );            
            return _promise; 
        },       
        uploadFile_init: function(uploadedFile){
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("uploadedFile", uploadedFile);
            var upload_promise =  _http.post("src/php/data.ajax.php",
                fd,
                {
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':undefined
                    },
                    transformRequest:angular.identity
                });

            return upload_promise;
        },
        uploadFile_init_for_compare: function(uploadedFile){
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("uploadedFileForCompare", uploadedFile);
            var upload_promise =  _http.post("src/php/data.ajax.php",
                fd,
                {
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':undefined
                    },
                    transformRequest:angular.identity
                });

            return upload_promise;
        }     
    }   
}]);
```

Above mentioned Service contains 3 sub-Services:

- init
- uploadFile_init_for_compare
- uploadFile_init

And you can call sub-Services from controller like:

```
ajax_post.init(/**/);
ajax_post.uploadFile_init_for_compare(/**/);
ajax_post.uploadFile_init(/**/);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess my thinking of why not is that you lose the explicit declaration in the controller of what data/methods are available to the view. Not sure how important that counts as being ?